# Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display launching background GTK

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, centos, gtk, kvm

I have centos 6 minimal (headless) as a Host and installed ubuntu 14.04 Desktop as a guest and using KVM. 
There is a web application deployed inside Guest, and it opens and closes one GTK application (javafx) in background.
I am invoking this web app from my host thru ssh as "curl http://guest/myapp/start"
I observed the logs in Guest OS and see the error message "Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display"

I didn't understand the reason for this error.
1) This GTK app is not opening any window physically in ssh console on host and moreover it's background.
2) Guest is desktop version.

Can any one help me how to resolve this. I can't enable XWindows due to security requirements by the client.

Thanks,
Sridhar

Comment: What display do you think this app should use when you start it this way?

Answer (score 4):

This warning appears when we try to execute some command on remote machine using ssh, which needs to open window. Consider for example if you want to pull code from a remote repository using git clone. Here you need to enter password. But since you are using ssh on terminal it is unable to open a new window. Hence it throws this warning.
You can use vnc as a workaround as it is able to open any new window

Comment: So, then, it's impossible to run things I need to do on a headless Linux box? And this is an actual operating system that is supposed to be usable for servers???

Answer (score 0):

"Gtk: cannot open display" Which means it can not find display attached with device so if you have connected display you can export its address. generally it will be 0.0 So your command will be like "export DISPLAY=:0.0" if doesn't work try changing 0.0 to 0 then it can find the display. may be this link will be helpful https://askubuntu.com/questions/47642/how-to-start-a-gui-software-on-a-remote-linux-pc-via-ssh

Answer (score 0):

At the user's terminal (AND as that user NOT sudo or root), add localhost to the xhost permission. Type

```
$ xhost +localhost
```

And this allows the system-config-printer to run.

Answer (score -1):

You can't run a GTK+ application without a display.