# What is a viable workflow for remote Flutter development on a headless Raspberry Pi?

Tags: flutter, raspberry-pi, remote-debugging

I am struggling to find a viable workflow for developing a Flutter app on a headless Raspberry Pi.  I've already tried VNC with VSCode running direct on the RPi and it works OK, the latency is super annoying though.  I figure there must be a way to do this SSH, where I code remotely from my desktop and the app runs on the RPi.  I've used the VS Code SSH remote utility and it works for doing the editing, but will not work for debugging.  I can't get `flutter run` to work via SSH.  I only come up with the following errors:

```
...        
Building Linux application... (completed in 118.7s)
[  +95 ms] Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
[   +1 ms] (newapp:11641): Gtk-WARNING **: 14:15:24.633: cannot open display: 
[  +19 ms] Error waiting for a debug connection: The log reader stopped unexpectedly, or never started.
[   +8 ms] Error launching application on Linux.
[  +16 ms] "flutter run" took 121,211ms.
```

'newapp' is a standard flutter counter app.

Any advice on workflow would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me like this code tries to run a graphical app on a headless (no graphics) raspberry pi. Do you want to run the app on your desktop?

Comment: This is a Raspberry Pi 4, it has full graphics capabilities.  I have already tried VNC, and as stated, it works but is laggy.  I'm looking for a better option.  I am trying to run the app on the Pi.  I can build the app on the Pi using VS Code running on my desktop over SSH.  I just can't get the app to open in a debugging state on the Pi.

Comment: Similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468421/gtk-warning-cannot-open-display-launching-background-gtk